# HTML behaving inline with float left menu

Tags: html, css

I have a simple menu system made out of an unordered list. Below this menu I want to display content normally. However no matter how many DIVs I use, the content I want to show flows along with the menu items like so :

[image]

My HTML looks like this :

```
<div>
  <div id="tabs">
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li>Menu 1</li>
        <li>Menu 2</li>
        <li>Menu 3</li>
        <li>Menu 4</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>

    <div>
      <pre><span style="font-size: 11px">
asdf asfd asfd asdf asdf
asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf
asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf
asdf asdf asfd asdf asdf
asfd asdf asfd

</span></pre>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

And I am styling it like so :

```
#tabs ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#tabs li {
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-bottom-width: 0;
  margin: 3px 3px 0px 3px;
  padding: 5px 5px 0px 5px;
  background-color: #CCC;
  color: #696969;
}
```

Fiddle :

https://jsfiddle.net/b8udxhdh/

How do I prevent my content code behaving inline?

Answer (score 1):

The [CSS clear property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clear) should fix it.

I managed to fix your fiddle with just

```
#mainView { clear: both; }
```

Comment: yes, that works but now I have a float right section which is getting in the way. I think i just need to do clear:left

Answer (score 1):

you'll have to turn your #tabs ul as a block element, it's been treated as an inline element. You can do it by adding the "display: block" property on yours #tabs ul css selector

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your CSS file, I believe it'll resolve your issue.

```
  #tabs li {
     /* float: left; */
    display: inline-block;
}
```